# Cannot log into user account on LightDM nor TTY

Tags: arch-linux, users, password

After fixing pacman using a live USB installation, something peculiar occurred.

When I attempt to log into my user account on the LightDM login screen, it informs me that I have entered the wrong password. The same issue arises when I open a TTY.

This is not however a keymap issues, as outlined in https://askubuntu.com/questions/205121/cannot-login-to-any-ttys-wrong-password, because I have no problem logging into root, which has the same password set.

Once I log into a window manager using root, I can `su` into my user account. At that point, I no longer have root privileges and `su $USER` prompts for a password. My usual password is accepted here unlike the other method. As such, I know the password is correct. I have also reset my pssword using `passwd` multiple times, with no changes.

What could be happening here?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out, the shell I was using (fish) was broken. Changing the shell back to `/bin/bash`, then logging in, reinstalling fish and setting the shell back to `/bin/fish` solved the problem